# Linux virtualhost subdirectories not working

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I can only access 1 website '/resume/', sub directory websites are not visible externally? The site '/resume2/' tries to point to /resume/. All the sub sites are trying to point to /resume/

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName resume
 ServerAlias resume
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/resume/"
<Directory /var/www/html/resume/>
  DirectoryIndex index.php phpinfo.php index.html index.htm  
  Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName resume2
 ServerAlias resume2
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/resume2/"
<Directory /var/www/html/resume2/>
  DirectoryIndex index.php phpinfo.php index.html index.htm  
  Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you should define different hostnames/IPs or port behind the VirtualHost tag, e.g.

```
<VirtualHost resume.mydomain.de:80>
 ServerAlias resume
 ServerName resume.mydomain.de
 DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/resume/"
 ...
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost resume2.mydomain.de:80>
 ServerAlias resume
 ServerName resume.mydomain.de
 DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/resume2/"
 ...
</VirtualHost>
```

... where *resume.mydomain.de* and *resume2.mydomain.de* are resolved to two different IP that are both configured on your host. You could also use the same IP and different port. Anyhow, keep in mind that you need to add a listen tag to your configuration for each VirtualHost.

Hope that helps! Cheers ...

Comment: Or if you actually want subdirectories then you could just have a single virtual host for resume, and use a symlink in the resume directory pointing to resume2, just make sure the `FollowSymlinks` option is turned on.

Comment: Exactly - and use VirtualHost for having several ports, IPs or host names

Comment: I forgot to mention...if you don't want to use symlinks for whatever reason, an alternative is to use the `Alias` directive: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias

Comment: I will try adding the hostname/domain name to each virtual host now. I also think I can do this using a subdomain like resume.mysite.com and resume2.mysite.com. And in godaddy I would create those sub A names. This is all pointing to a home server for my studies. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Adding the sub domain worked. resume2.mysite.com
I think Drupal forces sites in other directories inside /html/ to the main root site?

Comment: sorry, I'm not familar with Drupal -